# Flutter :- Align a icon to the right bottom of a container

Tags: image, flutter, icons, alignment, containers

[image: Expectastions]

I tried a column with an aligned icon but it didn't display correctly

[image: Reality]

If anyone has any idea to help. It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

This is my code that i tried

````
    List<Widget> temp = [];
    listAirline.map((airline) {
      listAirlineName.map((item) {
        if (airline.name == item) {
          temp.add(
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 20,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(100.0, 60.0)),
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "images/Airlines/" + airline.id + ".jpg",
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.remove_circle,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      }).toList();
    }).toList();

    return temp;
  }```
````

Comment: @Dohan, please check the below solution and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the **`Stack`** widget for it, i have done similar task with the use of the Stack widget, please check the below solution

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomeScreen();
  }
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Home"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            height: 100.0,
            child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.15,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.4,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(20.0, 20.0)),
                  ),

                ),
              )
              ,
              Positioned(
                right: 5.0,
                bottom: 0.0,
                child:
                   Icon(
                    Icons.remove_circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),

              )
            ],
          ),
        )));
  }

  
}
```

And output of the above code is as follow
[image]

Comment: `Stack` is not a good solution as you have to use some magic numbers like `5` to center `x` icon at the bottom right corner - if you have that icon with unknown size (and you cannot know the default size of `Icon`) that `Stack` will not work - for that case you can use `Align` as in my comment above or `SizedOverflowBox`

Comment: something like: `child: Center(
  child: Container(
    // width: 100,
    // height: 100,
    color: Colors.green,
    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
    child: SizedOverflowBox(
      size: Size.zero,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Material(type: MaterialType.circle, color: Colors.white, child: Icon(Icons.add)),
    ),
  ),
),`