# Flutter how to style stack widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can i style my Stack widget in flutter to obtain such a layout

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter :- Align a icon to the right bottom of a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61223103/flutter-align-a-icon-to-the-right-bottom-of-a-container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use the `Stack` widget to place the two views on top of each other.
2. Apply a `boxShadow` to the smaller container to give it the kind of effect present in the view.

---

I added a demo:

```dart
Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 80,
          width: 80,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.purple,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'b',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0, // change the values to preferred values
          right: 5, // change the values to preferred values
          child: Container(
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  offset: Offset(0.0, 1),
                  spreadRadius: 2,
                  blurRadius: 2,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(
                    0.2,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.camera,
                size: 15,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

RESULT:

[image: result]